# Driving LEDs / other small loads with a 74HC06 or similar inverter

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, cmos, ttl

I was recently reverse-engineering some firmware (and other bits) from a router, and spotted that the front panel LEDs were driven from a 74HC06 hex inverter gate chip rather than a proper LED driver.

A little confused, I pulled up the datasheet and found that the chip could drive as much as 35mA, which seems like a cool trick - you can strobe two low-current LEDs at once, save yourself a bunch of separate transistors, and drive everything from a single cheap IC.

After digging around further, I found other inverter and buffer gate ICs that can sink up to a couple hundred milliamps in a small package, with a lower cost than even buying a bunch of 2n2222 transistors. This seems absolutely ideal for driving small loads from a microcontroller.

Is this really a common trick? Am I missing something here? Anything tricky that I should be aware of?

Comment: Note that 74x06 / 74x07 are open collector (not a standard inverter as you imply). And see also ULN2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you observe the datasheet limits (as you seem to have done) there are no real tricks here. A typical microcontroller may contain thousands to millions of transistors so tend to be fabricated using processes suited to to higher density logic instead of being aimed at high-current / power dissipation.

Those simple gates / drivers might contain in the order of dozens of transistors so use different processes, so if you find a part where the datasheet meets your needs go for it.

Just as a further comment, in high-volume commercial designs sometimes the reason the 'trick' isn't used is that when machine placed the transistors and a few resistors often work out cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

This definitely works. Often you'll find that the device can sink more current than it can source, so use it in an open-drain configuration. Shift registers are another good one to use; I have some waiting for a project where they will be driven from a microcontroller's SPI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You should remember, though, that a proper LED driver is not replaced by this sort of thing. In fact, to a degree (IIRC 8mA) you could even drive an LED using an AVR pin. Thats really more than enough for most indicator LED kind of requirements.

A proper LED driver doesn't just boost the current output. It usually is a current source instead of a voltage source, and therefore allows you to reduce or even eliminate the dissipation across the series resistor you would use when an LED is powered by 5V, or really any typical voltage source.  The buffer output or inverter output is designed specifically to be a voltage source, and a good one at that, meaning you don't get the sometimes significant advantage of not having to drop many volts across a series resistor, and subsequently being able to pump more power through the LED before you have to start worrying about the resistor overheating and/or failing.

Comment: Current source LED drivers are not the last word in saving power dissapation. These drivers are usually driven from some fixed voltage. When a constant current driver is sourcing or sinking current from an LED where do you suppose that the excess voltage drop goes beyond what the LED drops. Yeah!! It is dropped across the current source/sink output causing a power dissipation that is proportional to this voltage drop and the supplied constant current. So even though you may be able to eliminate the power dissipation a series resistor it ends up going someplace else. (cont next comment)

Comment: (cont from prev comment) Some times when constant current drives are used to drive LEDs off a fixed voltage source series resistors are still placed in the circuit to help share the power dissipation. The ideal LED driver is one that uses a switching design to step the voltage for the constant current driver down to a level just enough over the LED forward voltage that the power dissipation in the driver is minimized as much as possible. This of course needs to be evaluated carefully and may only to prove efficient when the LED (still too long...argh)

Comment: (cont from above) current levels are quite high. For your stock simple 10mA indicator or front panel LED the simplest/cheapest driver may still be the best choice.

Comment: If there are LED driver ICs which are linear, which, admittedly, is a possibility I did not consider since I would not see the point of using one for anything I've needed a driver for. And 10mA for an indicator is rather steep, if you ask me. But I suppose when you're designing based on what's available, it's fair to be constrained in such manner.

Comment: The biggest advantage of constant-current drivers is that they allow LED brightness to remain consistent even if the drive voltage isn't.  Especially before switching power supplies became so cheap, this was helpful for maximizing battery life, since an LED with a 1.7-volt drop could be operated from a 3-volt battery down to about 2 volts (assuming the rest of the circuitry could handle that).  If one were using a resistor and sized it for proper brightness at 3 volts, brightness would drop by ~85% by the time the battery got down to two volts.